# Pandas: How to get the sample rows from each category from specific column in dataframe and save in single csv?

Tags: python, pandas

Below is the dataframe (df). I want to save the sample of 3 rows from each category of 'country' column.
Following is my code but it's not saving based on category. I need single csv having the samples. Please suggest.

```
data = {'country':['India', 'Nepal', 'Canada', 'USA','India', 'Nepal', 'Canada', 'USA','India', 'Nepal', 'Canada', 'USA','India', 'Nepal', 'Canada', 'USA','India', 'Nepal', 'Canada', 'USA'],
    'Age':[20, 21, 19, 18,20, 21, 19, 18,20, 21, 19, 18,20, 21, 19, 18,20, 21, 19, 18]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.sample(n=3).to_csv(sampledata.csv, na_rep='NA', index = False)
```

Answer (score 2):

GroupBy and then sample

```
df.groupby('country').sample(3)

   country  Age
2   Canada   19
6   Canada   19
10  Canada   19
4    India   20
0    India   20
12   India   20
1    Nepal   21
13   Nepal   21
9    Nepal   21
3      USA   18
11     USA   18
19     USA   18
```

Comment: Getting the following error: AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'sample' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? `df.groupby.sample` was added in, I believe, pandas 1.1 and greater.

Comment: the version that I am using is 3.7 version

Comment: @John83 that is the python version. What version of pandas are you using: `pd.__version__`

Comment: This is the one..'0.25.1'

Comment: So, this answer will not work for that version of pandas. `df.groupby.sample` only works in pandas 1.1.0 or greater.

Comment: If you can update pandas then I would do that. Pandas 0.25 is very old.